# CSS3 transform rotate "by" n degrees

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have a cube (well almost) made up of 4 divs which I'm rotating using CSS3 transforms (currently limited to -webkit as this is for a Chrome extension.)

However, you'll see that if you go to http://jsfiddle.net/CxYTg/ and click "one", "two", "three", "four", and then on "one" again, the last rotation goes in the opposite direction to reset back to the original orientation.

Is there a way to fix this using CSS3? I'm wondering if there's a way to do something like:

```
#environment li.rota180:first-of-type .cubeface { -webkit-transform: rotateY( "by 90deg") translate3d(0, 0, 100px); }
```

(And yes, I know I could just do this using JavaScript - but I'd like to find out if it's possible to do it through CSS only.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it with pure css.
For implementing this the way you wanted, you need variables and conditions, Use javascript it's easier. 
All you need to do is create two variables one for the degrees and one for remembering the current box. The rest is just conditions.